# ORACLE: How to Bulk collect master & details in one query?

Tags: bulk, oracle19c

Lets say we have the usual Oracle Employees and Departments tables.

I also have some Oracle Object types:

- TEmployee: an object type that has the same members as fields in Table Employees.
- TEmployeeList: an object table of TEmployee.
- TDepartment: an object type that has the same members as fields in Table Departments.
- TDepartment also has a member "employees" of type TEmployeeList.
  TDepartmentList: an object table of TDepartment.

Now I want to bulk collect a number of departments with their employees in a single query.

I know how to bulk collect the departments without the employees:

```
DECLARE
  departmentList TDepartmentList;
BEGIN

  SELECT TDepartment(dept.id, dept.name)
  BULK COLLECT INTO departmentList
  FROM departments dept
  WHERE <some condition>;

END;
```

But how can I collect the employees of the selected departments in the same query?

Thus something like

```
DECLARE
  departmentList TDepartmentList;
BEGIN

  SELECT TDepartment(dept.id, dept.name,
          SELECT TEmployee(emp.id, emp.name)
          FROM Employees
          WHERE emp.deptId = dept.id
  )
  BULK COLLECT INTO departmentList
  FROM departments dept
  WHERE <some condition>;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it:

```
DECLARE
  departmentList TDepartmentList;
BEGIN

  SELECT TDepartment(dept.id, dept.name,
      CAST(MULTISET(
          SELECT TEmployee(emp.id, emp.name)
          FROM Employees
          WHERE emp.deptId = dept.id
      ) AS TEmployeeList))
  )
  BULK COLLECT INTO departmentList
  FROM departments dept
  WHERE <some condition>;

END;
```

So the `CAST(MULTISET( query ) AS TEmployeeList)` is what I added.